# Application Status check using Stackdriver in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I have an application running in google compute instance (ps -ef | grep myapp). 
I want to setup an alert if the application goes down and/or comes up in google cloud Stackdriver.
How to achieve this ?

Comment: You will need to write your own program/script to accomplish this detection and alerting. Take a look at the Stackdriver APIs.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any references/documentation link to it ?

Comment: As I mentioned look at the Stackdriver APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alert on the [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts). You will have the option to either have the alert displayed as an incident on the Stackdriver monitoring console or as a notification via an email.

Before configuring your alerts, you will need to choose a [metric type](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) in which the alert will be based on.

If you cannot find a metric type that matches your needs, you will need to create your own [custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics).

I also found this [approach](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-push-serial-console-output-logs-to-stackdriver-and-set-alerts-in-gcp-9c88c6401d2) which will collect and the send the logs from the serial port to the Stackdriver logs. You will then be able to manipulate the data collected as you see fit.